# Casting Session variable in php

Tags: php, class, session-variables

Why can't i do this

```
$obj = new User();
$obj->emailid = $data->emailid;
$obj->password = $data->password;
$_SESSION["userinfo"] = $obj;
```

When i try to access this object back i have following error.

```
$obj = $_SESSION["userinfo"];
echo $object->emailid;
```

Please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I think you have a wrong typo? echo $object->emailid; ==> echo $obj->emailid;

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
$obj = $_SESSION["userinfo"];
echo $obj->emailid;
```